# C# dictionary json data to java class object

Tags: c#, android, json

I'm having a json data like

```
{ "1": "AAAA", "2": "BBBB","3":"CCCC","4":"DDDD","5":"EEEE"}
```

It's constructed by c# dictionary and send response to android client. And i'm having class at java like

```
public class Customer {

    int customerId;
    String customerName;
}
```

how to parse or assign json value to this class in java

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
String json = "{ \"1\" : \"AAA\", \"2\" : \"BBB\" }";
JSONObject object = null;
try {
    object = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
Iterator<String> i = (Iterator<String>)object.keys();
ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String key = i.next();
    String name = null;
    try {
        name = object.getString(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.customerId = Integer.parseInt(key);
    c.customerName = name;
    customers.add(c);
}
```